# Разные манифест файлы для разных версий

Tags: android, android-manifest

В проекте 2 разных варианта приложения:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        tatneft{
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".tatneft"
        }
        rosneft{
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".rosneft"
        }
    }
```

Как мне добавить второй манифест файл для проекта **rosneft**? так чтобы добавить в этот манифест некоторые дополнения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось все просто.
В папке ~Project\app\src\rosneft\
Создаем файл **AndroidManifest.xml**
*package="ru.scorp.tatneft" - оставляем основного проекта*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.scorp.tatneft">


<!--какие то параметры для проекта rosneft-->



</manifest>
```